# Driving conditions between Colorado Springs and Taos in January

Tags: driving, road-trips

I are looking to drive from Colorado Springs, CO to Taos, NM and back in early January 2017.  The two routes we looked at were going through La Veta pass (through Grand Junction) or Raton pass (through Angel Fire).

For those that regularly drive this during the winter:

> Aside from storms, snow chains and emergency gear, are there any
>   specific areas to be concerned about on either of those drives, or
>   things to be especially aware of?

Comment: What is your definition of "safest"? Generally the drive looks like four hours of typical American highways, if it isn't snowing. If it is snowing, you either wait for the plows to do their thing or you drive more carefully.

Comment: In research, the other routes offered by google maps (US 285) was said to go to much higher elevation and the roads aren't cleared as quickly.  The suggestions were to bring tire chains and tow rope.  The hope is to stay on the roads that have the best chance of being clear

Comment: So you just want to avoid putting on snow chains? That might not be possible. They're pretty much a part of life for everyone in the Rockies; if you can't push your drive back a few hours or a day in case of bad weather, then you'll possibly even need them on I-25.

Comment: Sorry, but how is "what is the usual road condition in January" for a specific stretch of road 'unclear'???

Comment: As an FYI, any number of highways in northern NM have signs saying they are not plowed (or patrolled by police) at night. I usually carry a good winter sleeping bag in my car when heading up to cross country ski in the back country in that general area so I can pull over and go to sleep while I wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you driven in snow country before?

No matter which route you take, blowing and drifting snow will be more of a concern than falling snow. Falling snow you can find out where it is on the weather report, blowing and drifting snow changes with the wind.  Keep the eyes open and try to drive around the small drifts rather than over them.  And there is lots of open space along your route which means lots of potential for blowing and drifting snow.

If the weather calls for snow storms, then sticking with major highways like I-25 is better, as they tend to be better taken care of to keep transport operating.

You mention having an 4WD SUV, a rental one might guess?  Assuming that you don't have a lot of snow country driving experience, my advice is don't let the SUV lull you into a sense of safety.  SUVs are NOT safer nor better for winter driving.  They actually have a higher center of gravity than a sedan so are more apt to spin and slide.  And while 4WD is better to get out of being stuck in the snow, it provides no added value when traveling at highway speeds.

Comment: We will actually be road tripping, and last year we drove from Missouri to Colorado Springs, Denver and then Grand Lake, CO between Christmas and New Years last year.  I guess my question is more around are snow chains a requirement for any driving through that area (we did not have them driving through passes and switchbacks last year between Empire, CO and Winter Park, CO), and aside from snow storms blowing through, is it reasonable to assume that the roads will be mostly clear (minus drifts/blown snow)?